# Saving .h5 file to SQL database

Tags: python, sql-server, hdf5

I've built a few neural networks using Python/Keras. I save the weights on my local machine the standard Keras way, as .h5 files. I'm not too familiar with the h5/hdf5 protocol, but I would like to save these .h5 files to my SQL database, where my data is.

Currently, I'm just saving the paths - is there a way to blob .h5 files to SQL Server?

Comment: You can store files in the database. You would use the varbinary(max) datatype for this. But you will have to pull them back out before you can use them anyway. You can also store files using filestream. Or you can store the path. There are ups and downs of each approach. These have all been discussed around here and the rest of the internet thousands of times.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the h5 file to sql server under varbinary(max) data type. If you are looking for the insert query:

```
INSERT INTO [model_table]
       ([model_weights])
 VALUES
       ((SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Path\to\model_weights.h5', SINGLE_BLOB) AS X))
```